# How to show GWT Hover text on a click

Tags: gwt, hover, click

I have as question mark icon with hover text attached.  If the user puts their mouse over the icon and waits a second, the hover text shows up.  However, if the user gets impatient and clicks on the icon, nothing happens, ever.

How can I make it so the hover text shows up on a hover or on a click?

Thank you,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Currently you use "title" property to show a tooltip. If you add a click event, you run the risk of showing two "tooltips" at the same time. The clean solution is not to use "title" property at all and use a PopupPanel instead with a simple MouseOver handler:

```
myWidget.addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
        myTooltipPopupPanel.showRelativeTo(myWidget);
    }

}, MouseOverEvent.getType());
```

Obviously, if you can add a MouseOverHandler directly to `myWidget`, there is no need to add it as a DomHandler.